# ¿Cómo identidicar un cambio en una columna en Pandas Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

Buen día
Estoy leyendo un archivo excel con Pandas y el dataframe que se crea es algo parecido al siguiente

| Nombres | Español | Ingles | Frances | Portugues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nombre1 | 5 | 4 | 9 | 10 |
| Nombre1 | 5 | 10 | nan | nan |
| Nombre2 | 5 | 6 | 1 | nan |
| Nombre2 | 5 | 7 | 5 | nan |
| Nombre3 | 5 | 3 | 6 | nan |

Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer los valores donde se comparta el mismo nombre, lo intente hacer con *.ffill* pero al hacerlo el valor recorre todos los espacios vacios sin importar que el nombre haya cambiando dando lo siguiente

| Nombres | Español | Ingles | Frances | Portugues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nombre1 | 5 | 4 | 9 | 10 |
| Nombre1 | 5 | 10 | nan | 10 |
| Nombre2 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 10 |
| Nombre2 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 10 |
| Nombre3 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 10 |

Pero solo me gustaría recorrer el valor cuando comparte el mismo nombre, hay alguna manera para hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agrupar primero en base a la columna *"Nombres"* haciendo uso de `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill`, por ejemplo:

```
import io                                                                                       
import pandas as pd                                                                             
                                                                                                
table = io.StringIO("""                                                                         
Nombres    Español    Ingles    Frances    Portugues                                            
Nombre1          5         4          9           10                                            
Nombre1          5        10        nan          nan                                            
Nombre2          5         6          1          nan                                            
Nombre2          5         7          5          nan                                            
Nombre3          5         3          6          nan                                            
""")                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
df = pd.read_table(table, sep='\\s+')
```

---

```
>>> df[["Español", "Ingles", "Frances", "Portugues"]] = df.groupby("Nombres").ffill()                                                                       
>>> df
   Nombres  Español  Ingles  Frances  Portugues
0  Nombre1        5       4      9.0       10.0
1  Nombre1        5      10      9.0       10.0
2  Nombre2        5       6      1.0        NaN
3  Nombre2        5       7      5.0        NaN
4  Nombre3        5       3      6.0        NaN
```

o si quieres aplicarlo solo a una columna (o a algunas de ellas) simplemente selecciónalas:

```
>>> df["Portugues"] = df.groupby("Nombres")["Portugues"].ffill()
>>> df
   Nombres  Español  Ingles  Frances  Portugues
0  Nombre1        5       4      9.0       10.0
1  Nombre1        5      10      NaN       10.0
2  Nombre2        5       6      1.0        NaN
3  Nombre2        5       7      5.0        NaN
4  Nombre3        5       3      6.0        NaN
```

También puedes conseguirlo usando `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply` y `pandas.Series.ffill`:

```
df = df.groupby("Nombres").apply(pd.Series.ffill).reset_index(drop=True)
```